How to remove vertical blue line when hovering over combobox items?
I'm using PySide6 and see a vertical blue line next to QComboBox items when hovering over them. I want to remove or customize them.
                combobox_style = """
        QComboBox {
            color: white;
            background-color: #4F4F4F;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        QComboBox:on {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        }
        QComboBox::drop-down {
            width: 20px;
            border-left-width: 0px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        QComboBox::down-arrow {
            image: url(./Pictures/60995.png);
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
        }
        QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
            color: white;
            background-color: #4F4F4F;
            selection-background-color: #666666;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        QComboBox::item {
            padding: 4px;
        }
        """


This is what I am expecting it to look like:

The blue line would be orange when hovering over the items and the backround would be orange when an item is selected.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You should probably use the ::item:selected pseudo selector to set the background color of selected items. Note that you can't separate the current and hover items by default (the hovering automatically makes the item as current for the view) unless you set a custom view on the combobox, but even in that case you should be very careful about event handling.

Qcombobox has selection-color and selection-background-color properties that can be set?

@RachelGallen Those properties are only used for the line edit selection, when the combo is editable. The view must have its own style sheet rules.

set boarder none on focus
